# add new env file to laravel for new server environment

Tags: laravel, development-environment, production-environment

i'm taking over a project from a client to add functionalities. I quite new in the development of Laravel 5.5

There are already 3 .env files in my project:
.env
.env.example
.env.live

.env.live is for production (APP/ENV=production) and runs on aws, the other 2 are for local use.

Now I have a new AWS EC2 server, database and so on and need a new env file to use these new instances. Let's say I create a new .env file called .env.dev

How how can I switch between the .env.dev and .env.live? Or how do I use this .env.dev?

Comment: You can add the environment variables to the EC2 server, then you don't need the `.env` files at all.

Comment: Laravel need some variables.. is that not a problem?

Comment: They can get them from the EC2 environment variables.

Comment: (At least that's what I did when using Elastic Beanstalk. If you're not using EB I'm not sure if you can do this.)

Comment: i'm using EC2 and RDS

Comment: I'd suggest shoving them (EC2 and RDS) in an Elastic Beanstalk environment, then setting the environment properties in there. It will also make them easier to manage, since you can deploy without worrying about committing your `.env` files to the repo (which is bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Elastic Beanstalk, go to your environment, then click the Configuration menu item. From there click "Modify" in the "Software" section. A page will appear where you can add Environment Properties as key->value pairs.

You can then delete the `.env` files. These properties will be read by your Laravel app just like it reads the `.env` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the symbolic links

Just Delete `.env` from both of the server and create a symbolic link like.

`ln -s .env.live .env // for live`

`ln -s .env.dev .env // for dev server`

You can also keep this command inside your deployment script if you are using any CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

On every server you only need `.env` file to execute. If you have three files

- .env
- .env.live
- .env.example
- .env.other

you can create multiple files with `.env.*`. But when you will execute your application then your `.env` file will execute.

Now if you want to add new additional settings to your environment then you just need to add in `.env` file. and also specify all other `.env.*` files and change values according to server.

When you will deploy your application on live server. Then you just need to rename your `.env.live` file to `.env` and set configurations to that file.

```
cp .env.live .env
```

*Note: if you already have `.env` file on your server(as you said your application is already on production server.) then you just need to add your environment settings to that file.*